# how to create bat file in mac os

Tags: batch-file, build, ant, sh

I am trying to make a bat file for Windows and a sh file for Mac using Ant Script in Eclipse for Mac.

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="ant.bat"/>
    <arg value="-p"/>
</exec>
```

But I am getting error build.xml:40: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/"): error=2, No such file or directory.

What's the problem?

Comment: cmd is a windows program which is not available on a mac.  Although you said you want to create the bat file the exec task you show here will not create the file ant.bat it will run it.

Comment: There is no `cmd` executable; it says it right there in the error text.

Comment: You are showing code that *executes* a batch file, not code that *creates* one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute bat file on mac, as bat files are specific to windows and you need its shell cmd.exe(which won't be available on mac).

You need to separate ant targets based on windows and mac and write conditional blocks to separate them so that ant will pick based on the OS you are running.

Check this [link](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-determine-operating-system-os-ant-build-script/) for reference.

Comment: I said that it creates a file, not an executable.

Comment: bat file will be executed by only cmd(windows shell).

Comment: Take it up a level... you should try to do whatever is in that bat file natively in ant. what does it do?